# Proof of system of linear equations solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let be vetors $(1, 2, 3,−1)$ and $(3, 6, 9,−3)$ a solutions of some system of  linear equations with factors from $R$. Prove that the vector $(0, 0, 0, 0)$ is also a solution of this system of linear equations.

Could you explain this, how can I prove it step by step? I will appreciate, if you give a complex interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$Ax = b$$

represent the given system of linear equations.

$x_1 = (1,2,3,-1)$ and $x_2 = (3,6,9,-3)$. Note that $x_2 = 3x_1$

$$Ax_1 = b$$
$$Ax_2 = b$$

$$A(x_2 - 3x_1) = -2b$$
$$\implies A(0,0,0,0) = -2b$$
$$\implies A(0,0,0,0) = b$$

Basically, $b$ is a null vector!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** In what relation do $(1,2,3,-1)$ and $(3,6,9,-3)$ stand to each other? Also, what do you know about linear combinations of solutions to linear systems?

Answer (score 1):

Hint

A*X = b

A*3X = b

Then

b = b/3, i.e. b = 0

Comment: Please use [mathjax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).